# How can I add multiple statements to DataGridView DataSource

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

In the system dt gets urls and I put them to getco.... function in there I call a sql statment then, I add it to gridview data source. But it gets last url's items so it overrides. How can i solve it?

```
     for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         row = dt.Rows[i];
         GridView1.DataSource = db.getComboxedCombinedRSS( row[0].ToString());
     }

     GridView1.DataBind();




public DataSet getComboxedCombinedRSS(string url)
{
    //SQL string to count the amount of rows within the OSDE_Users table
    //string sql = "SELECT [RSS_Title], [RSS_ID], R.Syndication, R.Category FROM RSS AS R INNER JOIN CombinedFeeds AS C ON  C.URL = R.URL  WHERE C.Name='" +name+" ' ORDER BY RSS_Date desc";
    string sql="SELECT top 30 [RSS_Title], [RSS_ID], Syndication, Category FROM RSS where URL= '"+url+"' order by RSS_DATE";
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Connect());
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapt.Fill(ds);

    // result of query filled into datasource
    adapt.Dispose();

    closeConnection();
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: ur loop is overwriting it. handle that

Comment: only leventkalay92 can do that :)What should the mechanism be? add each result set to dgv? keep only the first? keep a few and ignore the rest? you only have told the trouble u r facing, never the requirement..

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         row = dt.Rows[i];
        db.getComboxedCombinedRSS( row[0].ToString(), ds);
     }
     GridView1.DataSource = ds;
     GridView1.DataBind();




public void getComboxedCombinedRSS(string url, DataSet ds)
{
    //SQL string to count the amount of rows within the OSDE_Users table
    //string sql = "SELECT [RSS_Title], [RSS_ID], R.Syndication, R.Category FROM RSS AS R INNER JOIN CombinedFeeds AS C ON  C.URL = R.URL  WHERE C.Name='" +name+" ' ORDER BY RSS_Date desc";
    string sql="SELECT top 30 [RSS_Title], [RSS_ID], Syndication, Category FROM RSS where URL= '"+url+"' order by RSS_DATE";
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Connect());

    adapt.Fill(ds);

    // result of query filled into datasource
    adapt.Dispose();

    closeConnection();

}
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't add second one so else statement does not works ?

Comment: Is RSS_ID - primary key of RSS_DATE?

Comment: there is an error in getcomboxed function it returns ds but void function I am confused